# What does "BlackBerry-ing during a gorgeous party" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I came across the word "BlackBerry-ing" in [this *New York Times* article](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/01/28/nyregion/28mansion.html?_r=1&nl=todaysheadlines&emc=tha29&pagewanted=all) introducing New York governor Andrew M. Cuomo’s "Kitchen Diplomacy."

> More grizzled legislators were less impressed, with one senator recalling that during a question-and-answer period, "I was in the middle of BlackBerry-ing."

Though I guess it's a figurative remark insinuating "sit on the fence," I may be wrong. I have no clue where to find out what "BlackBerry-ing" means from the context of the above sentence. Can anybody tell me?

Comment: IMO, the senator should have said: "I was in the middle of *using my BlackBerry*".

Comment: I don't know where that "gorgeous party" came from. I can't see the word "gorgeous" anywhere in the linked article, and it really looks out of place in the question title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*BlackBerrying* simply means using one's [BlackBerry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry).

[image: BlackBerry]

So the senator found the question-and-answer session to be so [boring](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/boring#Adjective) that he used his BlackBerry to browse the Web, or check his emails, or something like that.

Comment: RegDwight. Thank you for your quich reply. Twitteing - that I can understand. But it's so hard for an old man like me to catch up new fashion and buzz words derived from cyber world.

Comment: @RedDwright: So SonyEricssoning, Nokiaing, iPhoneing are words too ?

Comment: @Mr. X: well, morphologically, they certainly are. They do have to get some traction, though. Google returns 17.5k results for  BlackBerrying, but nothing reliable for SonyEricssoning, Nokiaing, or even iPhoneing.

Comment: @Mr. X. The poster was asking for the meaning of a word found in an article. That the word wasn't an actual word but an expression of corporate America is irrelevant. One still needs to understand what was mean regardless of whether or not the word is considered standard.

Comment: Sylverdrag. That's right. I understood that the senator was Black-berrying. But is it all? Does Black-berrying action suggest that he (or she) was not interested in or ignoring Q & A session at all, or he just wanted to behave as a neutral between pro-Cuomo and anti-Cuomo members? I want to know that too.

Comment: Bonus points for a freehand circle around "Blackberry".

Comment: @RegDwight: *iPhoning* is more common than *iPhoneing*

Comment: It's worth adding that colloquial English is perfectly happy for people to 'invent' words based on either common nouns or proper names: "I was sitting there, happily iPadding away..." (using an iPad) "So, take-away tonight? Are we kebab-ing or Chinese-ing?" (getting a take-away meal from a kebab shop or a Chinese restaurant)

Comment: It's also worth noting that the writer knew perfectly well he was using a relatively unfamiliar neologism, which is why he capitalised and included a hyphen to make it even more obvious the proper noun **Blackberry** was the operative word.

Comment: @YoichiOishi it would seem that being bored most likely *is* all.  Earlier: "A few...could not resist gushing about the décor" then "More grizzled legislators were less impressed..." implying that the senator was on his Blackberry because he was bored and the "wining-and-dining routine" did not work for him.